# How can I get the Suffrage badge? The number doesn't change in accordance with the votes I have casted

Tags: support, badges

How can I get the Suffrage badge? The number doesn't change in accordance with the votes I have casted.

I have casted many upvotes and downvotes today, on questions and answers of different users, but the number stays at 13, exactly what vote counts?

Thanks in advance.

---

It has changed to 17, however I have casted more than 4 votes since when it was 13...

---

Now it is 18 after refreshing, but after casting another vote and immediately refreshing the user profile page, it doesn't change to 19, is this a bug or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caching. Right now, it shows as 21 to me on [your profile](https://superuser.com/users/1250181/xe%d0%bd%ce%b5i-%ce%9e%d1%8dn%d0%b2%cf%b5%cf%82?tab=topactivity), both in the badge tracker as in the Votes cast:

[image]
[image]

There is a [Votes tab](https://superuser.com/users/442468/current?tab=votes&sort=all) on your own profile (we can't see it) to check which votes you've cast. That *is* always up to date, but doesn't show votes on deleted posts. And you have to count the number of votes today manually.